# I want to navigate on list view to create a new list view on click of a new button through lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

Below is the  code I am using to navigate to list view

```
handleNewListView(){
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
             type: 'standard__objectPage',
             attributes: {
                 objectApiName:'ListView',
                 actionName: 'new'
             }
         });
    }
```

IT is giving error
This record is not supported

But when I am passing the standard object API name or custom object API name then it will open the standard component of that particular object to create the record.

Still, I want to know that a listview is a standard object or custom object.

Comment: Please do not repost questions. I've closed your other question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Still, I want to know that a listview is a standard object or custom object.

A list view is neither a standard object nor a custom object. It is a setup object, part of your Salesforce org's metadata. List Views are not createable using the REST or SOAP APIs (see the [SOAP Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_listview.htm)).

You will not be able to create List Views using any of the standard components that are intended to operate on sObjects. They do not have an object page.